# Reverse SSH tunneling for server running in Windows OS

Tags: networking, ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel

I'm hosting a server on ports 39083 and 39084 on my machine that has a private ip address. I'm looking to host the server using SSH tunneling, the request would go through my VPS ip address then to my machine that has the server running, how do I achieve this in Putty? My VPS is Windows Server 2008 and has OpenSSH installed.

I have tried these settings:

[image]

Event log:

[image]

I get connection refused error when client tries to connect to the server through VPSIpAddress:39083 when server is hosted on my machine, I can connect locally so I'm sure the server is listening. Hosting the server on the VPS is not an option.

Comment: you can click the tick by jeremy's answer

Comment: also you should have run "netstat -aon | grep 39083" on the vps., see if it shows 0.0.0.0 for example.. so see what it is bound to and if it is listening.

Comment: maybe ticking that box "remote ports do the same ssh2" would  / would have made a difference

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score -1):

Check out https://serverfault.com/q/387772. You most likely need to check the "Remote ports do the same". Without that, your reverse tunnel listener on VPS is likely binding to localhost.

Comment: Also, if that doesn't work, check the sshd_config configuration on your VPS box to make sure AllowTcpForwarding and GatewayPorts are both set to "yes".

Comment: This answer really should contain the relevant from the link you provided....

Comment: @Ramhound, since this is the second time you have chosen to downvote one of my answers, could you please educate me regarding what you believe a useful answer would be?

Comment: Voting is  anonymous, you being able to see my voting history is news to me, probably will report that bug to a CM.  in any event, I already provided my reason, read my comment that left 2 hours ago.  It's actually the secind, which is primarily a link, but failed to include ANY information from.  Your answers are popping up in the review which is the only reason  reason for the multiple votes I issued.  But again cool permission you have, CMs can't even see, my vote history outright

Comment: @Ramhound Apologies for my assumption. Let me restate. Since this is the second time you have chosen to comment that one of my answers is not sufficient, could you please educate me about what you believe a sufficient answer would be? My answer included the specific configuration change that I believe will solve the OPs problem, and a reference for additional information. I also provided additional steps in a comment. I am trying to become better at participating in this community. So again I ask you to provide me help determining what other information I should have provided.

Comment: So you provided all relevant information from that answer?  There is nothing you can add to your answer or quote from the linked question's answer?  The help center has information on links and answers of you want more broad approaching advice.  My original comment still seems clear though....have said it twice so far....literally what should change.